# Question on vectorspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Let V be a vector space over the ﬁeld F.

a)Let S be any set of vectors in V , and let W be the intersection of all subspaces of V which contain S (that is, x ∈ W if and only if x lies in every subspace which contains S). Prove that W is the set of ﬁnite linear combinations of vectors from S.

My idea is that as long as we show W=spans(s) then the problem is solved.

but how to proof S is the spanning set of W ?????

Comment: Careful; it is not true that S is the spanning set of W. Let W be the intersection set you described. Maybe you can first show that an intersection of subspaces is a subspace (possibly the empty one). Then you have that the elements of S are in a vector space, so that, by vector space properties, every finite linear combination of vectors in S is also in S. So W contains the set of all finite linear combinations of elements of S. Now, consider the set of all finite linear combinations of elements of S. Can you prove S is contained in W?

Comment: So do u mean I need to prove both span(S) in W and W in span(S) to show Span(S)=W?????

Comment: @Raymondwu Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

**Proof outline:** Consider the set $K$ of finite linear combinations of elements of $S$. It is a vector space that contains $S$, so $W\subseteq K$.

Also, $K$ is  contained in every vector space that contains $S$, so $K\subseteq W$.

Comment: but how do u know the vector space W is bigger, smaller or equal to k?

Comment: We prove it is "smaller" and "bigger" so it is equal. The reason that $W\subseteq K$ is that $W$ is the **intersection** of all subspaces that contain $S$. But $K$ is such a subspace, so every element of $W$ must be in $K$. Recall that the intersection of a bunch of sets is the collection of points contained in *every one* of the sets. Since $K$ is one of those sets, the result follows. I have left a gap. You will have to show that the set of finite linear combinations of elements of $S$ really is a vector **subspace** of $V$ containing $S$. (The containing $S$ part is trivial.)

Comment: There is also a small amount of detail to fill in for the other direction (last sentence).